# My Ajax is sending post twice for php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I keep getting two posts on my table when I send my create.php for a smooth upload.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

/* Data Insert Starts Here */
$(document).submit('submit', '#SavePost', function () {

    $.post("create.php", $(this).serialize())
        .done(function (data) {
            $("#dis").fadeOut();
            $("#dis").fadeIn('slow', function () {
                $("#dis").html('<div class="alert alert-info">' + data + '</div>');
                $("#SavePost")[0].reset();
                $("body").fadeOut('slow', function () {
                    $("body").fadeOut('slow');
                    window.location.href = "index.php";
                });
            });
        });

    /* Image upload Ajax */
    $.ajax({
        url: "create.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
            //$("#preview").fadeOut();
            $("#err").fadeOut();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == 'invalid file') {
                // invalid file format.
                $("#err").html("Invalid File !").fadeIn();
            } else {
                // view uploaded file.
                $("#preview").html(data).fadeIn();
                $("#SavePost")[0].reset();
            }
        },
        error: function (e) {
            $("#err").html(e).fadeIn();
        }
    });
    /* Image upload Ajax ENDING */
    return false;
});
/* Data Insert Ends Here */
```

I get one post with the image uploaded and one without. I tried to check if my post get sent twice and i have tried to delete a few lines but i can't seem to figure this one out.

Thanks!

Comment: **My Ajax is sending post twice for php:** What is this `$.post("create.php", $(this).serialize())` and `$.ajax({
        url: "create.php",`?

Comment: You will get 2, because you are sending it twice. Once using `$.post` and second using `$.ajax`

Comment: You're doing it wrong, both `$.post` and `$.ajax` do *(almost)* the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.post` and `$.ajax` are **two seperate** request, so you are sending two requests, the first one via the `$.post` method and right after that you use `$.ajax` to send another request. remove one of them, and you will receive only one request as you expected.

Comment: Thanks for that Tobias! I removed the first part and kept the Ajax. I found out though that I needed to change the submit function. .submit    TO    .on with the ('submit', '#SavePost', function ()

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely that you're using a `button` or `submit` to trigger the ajax event.

You need to just add `e.preventDefault();`

Try to use like this:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr( 'action' ),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function( response ) {
                console.log( response );
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: `#exportForm` where is that? and how are you taking care of 2 requests?